# Getting log files from elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running a django project on elastic beanstalk. If I save my django log files to a paricular folder on my ec2 instance, is it possible to also get those when I run "eb logs -a"?

If so, what file path would I need to save my logs to on my instance?

Thanks!

Comment: Normally you can configure logs to go to s3 [eb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html). [eb logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html) should be able to pull from there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Customization of logs is generally  performed by means of `.ebextensions`:

- [Extending the default log task configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html#health-logs-extend)

**Amazon Linux 1** (AL1)

The EB documentation provides only information about AL1. Specifically, you can add your configuration of your custom logs to be reported by EB in two files:

- /opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/taillogs.d/ - for **tail** logs
- /opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/bundlelogs.d/ - for **full** logs

The link from docs have an example. But basically if your application produces some log files, you can bundle them all using the following section in your `.ebextensions` (example from docs):

```
files: 
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/bundlelogs.d/applogs.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      /var/app/current/log/*.log
```

`/var/app/current/log/*.log` would need to be adjusted to your application.

**Amazon Linux 2** (AL2)

Logging configuration is **undocumented** for AL2. But from my own dinging up, the AL2 log config folders are:

- /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/logtasks/tail - for **tail** logs
- /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/logtasks/bundle - for **full** logs

Thus, the example could be:

```
files: 
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/logtasks/bundle/applogs.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      /var/app/current/log/*.log
```

Comment: Marcin, can I pay you to help me with any aws questions? You are obviously an expert and I could use help in other areas.

Comment: @JasonHoward I'm fine thank you. If you have issues, please post them on SO. If not me, then someone else will try to help.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your contributions! You are an amazing asset to this community.

Comment: @JasonHoward No problem. Hopefully the logs will work. Its more difficult for me to verify that as its more specific to your application.

Comment: How would i know if I'm running on AL1 or 2? The instance screenshot just says I'm on Amazon Linux AMi release 2018-03. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonHoward This is AL1, which is lucky, because AWS doc I linked cover it.

Comment: My apologies. When specifying a destination for my django log files, would I indicate /var/app/current/log/ or /opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/bundlelogs.d/ ?

Comment: @JasonHoward No problem. In these config files you specify what are the log files you want to track. Thus you can store them in /var/app/current/log/ and tell eb to monitor all files with `*. log` extension: `/var/app/current/log/*.log` as in these examples.